# Excel fetch maximum() from column of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2019

I have tried all possible formulas I know to fetch maximum value where the available record date = current record date using both the index formula combined with the max function and likewise used vlookup but all to no avail. Below are the formulas.

=VLOOKUP(MAX(A2:A40), A2:C40, 0) , =INDEX(c2:C46,MATCH(MAX(a2:a40),a2:a40,0))

c2:c40 represents my amount column while a2:a40 represents my date column in the table while the current date = 5/12/2022

I have tried using if statements with max function and also used index()combined with match() and max() and vlooup/max()

Comment: so you want to return the max value from column C where the dates in column A match 5/12/2022, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
=MAXIFS(C2:C40, A2:A40, DATE(2022,12,5))
```

Assuming the date of your sample is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Instead of `DATE`, you can refer to the corresponding cell with the date value.

Comment: Did that already it still failed

Comment: @King you must be doing some error the previous approach should work in most of the excel version. Share a link to your file with edit permission, so I can take a look at it, to see what is going on. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, David Leal, I was able to later find the MAXIMUM value using this formula =IF(I4 = A2:A40, MAX(C2:C40)) and it worked. I4 here is where my date is stored to compare against all dates available in my date column. while C2:C40 contains the amount to be checked for maximum value.